# GCP - Where is BQ Table Explorer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am following [Data Science on Google Cloud Platform](https://www.amazon.com.au/Data-Science-Google-Cloud-Platform/), Chapter 3. It talks about **Table Explorer** table which is visible in the snapshot.

[image]

[image]

However, in the actual GCP project BQ console, there is no such tab. Has this **Table Explorer** been removed?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are currently in the BigQuery Sandbox, Can you confirm if there is a banner with highlighted **SANDBOX** text above your Explorer tab?

If that is the case, BigQuery Sandbox is like a preview state of the resource without setting up a billing account. It is subjected to [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sandbox#limitations) such as:

- All datasets have the default table expiration time,
- Streaming data is not supported
- Data Transfer Service is not supported and etc(Listed on the hyperlink above.)

To fully utilize BigQuery and access the Table Explorer tab you must enable billing for your project. Please visit this link for more information about upgrading from [BigQuery Sandbox](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sandbox#upgrade_from_the_sandbox)

Answer (score 0):

It's available in the [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery), once having selected a dataset: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui#displaying_resources